# Note be able to create tables in database and insert values

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MAMP as my localhost environment and i am trying to pass values from html form to database through php.when i submit my form i face following error:

> INSERT INTO social (facebook, google, twitter) VALUES ('sdf','sdf','sdf')
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'firsttest.social' doesn't exist

**html:**

```html
<html>
<form name='form' method='post' action="m.php">

Fb : <input type="text" name="fb" >
google : <input type="text" name="google" >
twitter : <input type="text" name="twitter" >

<input type="submit" name="save_to_db" value="Submit">  

</form>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['save_to_db'])){
   
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "firsttest";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE social (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    facebook VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    google VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    twitter VARCHAR(50),
    reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";
 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO social (facebook, google, twitter)
    VALUES ('".$_POST["fb"]."','".$_POST["google"]."','".$_POST["twitter"]."')";
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not executing the `CREATE TABLE` query, but instead, you overwrite it with the `INSERT` query instantly.

Try using a debug tool like xdebug or something, so you could walk step by step through your code, that will help you find bugs in your code easily.

Also, creating a database table each time you want to save data to the database is not wise. Try setting up the whole database before starting to work with it.

Comment: i am  a beginner in database.Thank you very much for your advise that's really something to keep in mind .